# Load csv file as a dataframe

Tags: python

This is a noob question, but without using Pandas (pd.read) how can I import a CSV file and load it to a DataFrame object so I can call it (e.g. print (loaded_file) ) and print the contents of the file in Python (2.7)?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name')
```

Comment: The question *just* mentioned without pandas...

Answer (score 2):

unicodecsv library can also be used to read .csv files.

```
import unicodecsv
import pandas as pd

def read_csv(data):
""" Returns a list of dicts from .csv file passed in as data"""
    with open(data, "rb") as f:
        reader = list(unicodecsv.DictReader(f))
        return reader

file = read_csv('filename.csv') # call the function and pass in your 'filename'

pd.DataFrame(file) # call pd.DataFrame() function with file as an argument 
                   # to convert it to DataFrame object
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read each line and split, also notice that you will need to know hoy to parse the types, for example:

```
def getCSV(filePath, sep=";"):
    with open(filePath, "r") as f:
        return [l.split(sep) for l in f]
```

then just load it into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
csvdata = getCSV("/da/real/path/file.csv")
pd.DataFrame(csvdata)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your last comment?

Comment: `getCSV` returns a list of lists (python lists) containing the data (string type) of the csv file. @Alvis

Comment: Ok great, thanks Daniel